# MarkLogic Upgrade and steps

Tags: upgrade, marklogic

Current version 9.0.7.0

Upgrade version 9.0.11.0

When we looked at how to upgrade, we found below link

[ML Knowledgebase](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/57/0/how-do-i-upgrade-from-one-version-of-marklogic-server-to-another)

This document is of April 2018.

So i would like to know if we have to follow any additional steps, configuration, process?

Answer (score 1):

## [Upgrading from Release 9.0-1 or Later](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/installation/procedures#id_77358)

> To upgrade from release 9.0-1 or later to the current MarkLogic 10 release (for example, if you are installing a maintenance release of MarkLogic 10), perform the following basic steps:
>
> 1. Stop MarkLogic Server (as described in step 1 of Removing MarkLogic).
> 2. Uninstall the old MarkLogic 9 release (as described in Removing MarkLogic).
>
>    2.1. If you want to uninstall MarkLogic 9.0-4 or later, and if the converters package was previously installed with it, you will have to perform a two-step uninstall: first uninstall MarkLogic Converters and then uninstall MarkLogic Server. For more detail, see MarkLogic Converters Installation Changes Starting at Release 9.0-4 and Removing MarkLogic.
> 3. Install the new MarkLogic 10 release (as described in Installing MarkLogic).
>      If you want to install MarkLogic 9.0-4 or later, and you plan to use the converters package with it, you will have to perform a two-step installation: first install MarkLogic Server and then install MarkLogic Converters. For more detail, see MarkLogic Converters Installation Changes Starting at Release 9.0-4 and Installing MarkLogic.
> 4. Start MarkLogic Server (as described in Starting MarkLogic Server).
> 5. Open the Admin Interface in a browser (http://localhost:8001/).
> 6. When the Admin Interface prompts you to upgrade the databases and the configuration files, click the button to confirm the upgrade.
>
> If you are upgrading a cluster to a new release, see Upgrading a Cluster to a New Maintenance Release of MarkLogic Server in the Scalability, Availability, and Failover Guide. The Security database and the Schemas database must be on the same host, and that host should be the first host you upgrade when upgrading a cluster.
>
> If you are upgrading two clusters that make use of database replication to replicate the Security database on the master cluster, then you must enter the following to manually upgrade the Security database configuration files on the machine that hosts the replica Security database:
>
> ```
> http://host:8001/security-upgrade-go.xqy?force=true
> ```